# TFS 2010 Prevent direct edits of Stage branch (only allow merge from Dev)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

I have the following scenario:

- I have a Dev and Stage branch
- Code is checked into Dev, and at some point those changesets from Dev are merged into Stage
- No direct edits/check-ins happen to stage (beyond the merges from dev)

What I want to do is identify/verify that no new code has been introduced directly into the stage branch which did not originate from a changeset in Dev.

It does not appear possible to secure Stage (from a source control perspective) to only allow check-ins of merges from dev (since all operations appear to be `merge,edit` after I do the merge), so what I thought I could do is create a TFS Check in policy which attempts to compare the merged changes to their source.

I have created a class which derives from `PolicyBase` and have over-ridden the `Evaluate` method.  In the `Evaluate` method, I spin through `this.PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChanges` and check the `.IsMerge` property and `.ServerItem` property to see if the item in question is a merge and is destined for my Stage branch.

When I spin through each change however, I don't see a way to track its lineage or access the parent from where it might have originated (ie: the Dev branch version #).

How do I only allow merges, but no direct edits on my Stage branch?

Comment: Looks like you're after: http://leon.mvps.org/TFS/MergeOnlyPolicy.aspx it includes the sources at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @jessehouwing I have actually implemented similar code. That code alone will not prevent someone from 'sneaking in' a change into Stage on a merged file.  When a merge is done from the Dev branch in the local workspace, prior to check in the developer can edit the source file which the merge was performed on and add additional code.  This is possible because the merge operation from Dev results in a 'merge, edit' operation on the Stage file in the workspace.  This code however does work great at blocking direct check-ins (edits) on the Stage branch on unmerged files.

Comment: Nothing will. because one always needs the ability to resolve Merge Conflicts. As long as you need to support merge conflict resolution, you'll need to allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this in TFVC is for you to take ownership of all merges. If you do the merge then you have the control. Many organizations with these sorts of draconian policies create an automated script that does the merge and rejects if there are any conflicts. That way the developer is forced to pull from Staging to Dev and resolve all conflicts before requesting the merge through a web portal. If the merge is successful it was conducted on a server by a single service account and no coder required permissions to Staging of any sort.

This is however dysfunctional. Either you don't trust your coders, or they are not competent enough to work in your code base.

Another method might be to move to Git in TFS for source control. In Git merges are non-editable and are performed as a single action rather than the merge/edit you get in TFVC.

Comment: This is not my policy; I have been however asked to come up with a way to enforce it.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: The only reason companies exist that treat their code and their people like this is because we let them.  I have been there too, which is why I became a change consultant to go fix them ... Does not always work...

Comment: Yeah, give everyone Check-out permission, but revoke the check-in permission except for a select few. Great way to cause frustration, late integration, bottlenecks and distrust all over.